# function in class, run only if variable is not set, PHP

Tags: php, function, return

I want to write function in class. I want to run this function only if one variable is not set.
I have 3 thoughts about this, but I do not know which one is best and looks "more professional".

1:

```
if (!isset($this->variable) {
     $this->functionXxx();
}
```

2:

```
private function functionXxx()
{
     if (!isset($this->variable)) {
         //code here
     } 
}
```

3:

```
private function functionXxx()
{
     if (isset($this->variable)) {
         return;
     } 
     //code here
}
```

Comment: Go with 2 option.

Comment: What is option `1` here? Do you using `$this` outside a class? Btw: `3` is beter than `2`, because you have to wrap all code in `2` in the `if`, but `3` is called `early return` behavior, and the rest of the code stand outside the `if`, that the function return `null` or `void` is ok.

Comment: Option 1 is inside class. It mean to not call method if variable isset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should stop call `methods` function.

Second, if `methodXxx` returns something after operation you can use 3rd option, but if `methodXxx` is what we call void function (returns nothing) than you should use 2nd option.